# How to make input-field seem like regular text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

In an ASP.NET application I have a lot of textbox controls that are displayed as readonly input fields. I want them to look like plain text. I tried a few things with styling and I have no luck so far (for example the disable attribute makes the text gray as well, and I am not sure if this works well with the ASP.NET databinding).

Is there a way to use styling/jquery to make an input field look like a plain text field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, you want an input field that is disabled look like plain text? I guess something like this should do:

HTML:

```
 <input type="text" value="This is an example." disabled="disabled"/>
```

CSS:

```
 input[type="text"]{
        border: none;
        background: transparent;
        color: #000;
    }
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z5HLS/) to check online.

Comment: This will make it look like text, but keep in mind anyone can use f12 and remove the disabled="disabled" attribute.  If you are then saving whatever is in the input, then they have successfully circumvented your disable logic.

Comment: Very Useful technique

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
background-color: #fff
```

?

Comment: Not yet to be honest. Will check it out tomorrow! Thanks.